Compare tibbles in list-columns to produce a new tibble-column with map
I have a tibble with a couple of list-columns, each containing nested tibbles. I want to produce a new list-column with tibbles resulting from a comparison of the nested ones in the existing list-columns.
EDIT: this is a toy example; real data have multiple rows. I'd also like to be able to use filter to run the comparison between the nested tibbles (the example here just uses equality == but actual comparison is more complex).
x <- tibble(a = list(tibble(val = seq(1:5))), b = list(tibble(val=c(2,5,3,4,1))))
x
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  a                b               
  <list>           <list>          
1 <tibble [5 × 1]> <tibble [5 × 1]>

x$a
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 × 1
    val
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5

x$b
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 × 1
    val
  <dbl>
1     2
2     5
3     3
4     4
5     1

Suppose I want to produce a new column x$c where the component tibbles are where val in the tibble nested in a is equal to that in b, i.e. the expected output here would be:
x$c
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 1
    val
  <int>
1     3
2     4

Doing this for a single row at a time is straightforward enough:
x$a[[1]] %>% filter(val == x$b[[1]]$val)
# A tibble: 2 × 1
    val
  <int>
1     3
2     4

But my real data has multiple rows and I want to do them all at once. I tried using mutate and map but am getting an error:
x %>% mutate(c = map(a, filter, val==b$val))
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `c = map(a, filter, val == b$val)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `.f()`:
ℹ In argument: `val == b$val`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of size 5 or 1, not size 0.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I believe this has something to do with the nesting structure and what exactly is being referenced in the filter statement; if I specify val==b[[1]]$val it doesn't give an error, but then the filter condition uses the first row tibble for b for all rows (which is fine for a single-row example but not for my real data).
How do I get map to work in this case such that each row's output is based on the appropriate comparison of that row's other nested tibbles?

Since you are passing two arguments (column a and b), use map2 instead of map. You can simply check for equality between a and b, then use this to subset a.
x2 <- x %>%
  mutate(c = map2(a, b, ~ .x[.x == .y,]))

x2$c
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>     val
#>   <int>
#> 1     3
#> 2     4


Thanks; I should clarify that in reality I am trying to use filter with some more complex conditions. Also, I believe the solution you give won't work for multiple rows, which my real data has

@TYLim see my update - this will work for multiple rows. If you have more complex requirements, please state them in your question.

Ah, good catch, I forgot about map2. Have edited question too.

In addition to @Allan's solution, since you've mentioned, here's a variation with dplyr::filter() explicitly.
Toy data:
library(tidyverse)
# -------------------

x <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,                                           ~a,                                           ~b,
  1L, tibble(val = c(2, 1, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 10, 6, 9)), tibble(val = c(2, 10, 1, 5, 2, 4, 9, 8, 6, 3)),
  2L, tibble(val = c(4, 6, 10, 9, 4, 8, 7, 3, 5, 1)), tibble(val = c(4, 3, 7, 1, 10, 9, 8, 5, 6, 2)),
  3L, tibble(val = c(4, 9, 6, 7, 9, 3, 10, 1, 5, 8)), tibble(val = c(10, 9, 8, 3, 9, 2, 4, 5, 1, 7)))

The code:
x1 <- x mutate(x, c = map2(a, b, \(x, y) filter(x, if_all(everything(), \(xx) xx == y))))

The unnested output:
> unnest_longer(x1, c)
# A tibble: 5 × 4
     id a                 b                 c$val
  <int> <list>            <list>            <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     2
2     1 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     6
3     2 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     4
4     3 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     9
5     3 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     9

One example with more conditions (a$val == lead(b$val)):
x1 <- mutate(x, c = map2(a, b, 
  \(x, y) filter(x, if_all(everything(), \(xx) xx == y) | x$val == lead(y$val))))

..and unnested:
> unnest_longer(x1, c)
# A tibble: 10 × 4
      id a                 b                 c$val
   <int> <list>            <list>            <dbl>
 1     1 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     2
 2     1 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     1
 3     1 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     5
 4     1 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     8
 5     1 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     6
 6     2 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     4
 7     2 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     8
 8     3 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     9
 9     3 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     9
10     3 <tibble [10 × 1]> <tibble [10 × 1]>     1

